# Can I do an ASP.NET Dynamic Data project against a Sybase database?

Tags: asp.net, sybase, dynamic-data

Or must it be a SQL Server database?  If I'm reading the documentation right, as long as I use Entity Framework and not Linq to SQL, I can go against a Sybase data source.  But I'm not certain...

Answer (score 0):

If you use EF you can use any database with an ADO.NET Data Provider.

Here is a list of available providers (including Sybase) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx